# django: batch update functions with join

Tags: django

I'm trying to find a way to mass update records based on an equation, here it is in it's simplest form

```
StoreLiquor.objects.filter(storeID=ID_Store, liquorID__BottleSize='375 ML').update(StorePrice = F('liquorID__ShelfPrice'))
```

But the problem is that the update function does not let me used joined tables. Is there a way around this?

Comment: What are your models, what error do you get?

Comment: You can't.  See the end of this section in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if there might be another way then that doesn't envolve using update()